# Python code not working - returning "Incorrect"

Tags: python

So, once I ran the code, the `question()` returns `'Incorrect'`, even I'm pretty sure that I put in the right answer.

P.S. The `operator()` function is alright I checked it; it's only the `question()` that needs attention.

```
import random

def numberRan(): # Generate a random number
   return random.randint(1, 10) # No arguments needed for this

def operator():
   operator = ""
   number = random.randint(1, 3)
   if number == 1:
      operator = "+"
   elif number == 2:
      operator = "-"
   else:
      operator = "x"
   return operator

def question():
   num1 = numberRan()
   num2 = numberRan()
   realAnswer = 0
   int(realAnswer)
   oper = operator()
   answer = input(str(num1) + str(oper) + str(num2) + "= ")
   if oper == "+":
      realAnswer = num1 + num2
   elif oper == "-":
      realAnswer = num1 - num2
   elif oper == "x":
      realAnswer = num1 * num2
   if realAnswer == answer:
      return "Correct"
   else:
      return "Incorrect"

question()
```

Comment: You never convert your answer to an int, so your answer (the result of `input(...)` is still a str. You're then comparing that str to `realAnswer`, which is an int: comparing an int and str will be always False.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never convert your answer to an int, so your answer (the result of `input(...)` is still a str. You're then comparing that str to `realAnswer`, which is an int: comparing an int and str will be always `False`.

Just change one line:

```
answer = input(str(num1) + str(oper) + str(num2) + "= ")
```

to

```
try:
    answer = int(input(str(num1) + str(oper) + str(num2) + "= "))
except ValueError:
    import sys
    sys.stderr.write("your input was not an integer number")
    return "Incorrect"

if oper == "+":
    ...
```

Note the try-except clause: now, there's an explanatory error message if the input was not a number.